# Subviews added to documentView of NSScrollView not showing up

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsscrollview

I have a `NSView` wrapped in a `NSScrollView` using the IB. In the initialization function of the view (class is `NoteView`) containing the `NSScrollView`, I attempt to add subviews to the `NSView` as follows:

```
// Initialize custom view with width 802 and height 130, call it initialSubview
// Set initialSubview's frame origin to (20.0, 580.0). documentView of scrollView
// is size (842.0, 740.0)
// Let innerView be the documentView of the scrollView (I have an IBOutlet attaching
// the scrollView's document view to innerView)

[innerView addSubview:initialSubview];
```

When I do this, nothing shows up. Likewise, trying this:

```
[[[scrollView] documentView] addSubview:initialSubview];
```

doesn't work either. However, if I added it to the contentView:

```
[[[scrollView] contentView] addSubview:initialSubview];
```

The subview shows up fine. Any ideas?
As an addendum, if I add something like an `NSButton` to the documentView in the IB, nothing
shows up as well.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue. It seems NSScrollView and Auto-layout fight themselves.
The solution is to remove whatever you're documentView is (in my case innerView)
from their superview, setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskToConstraints to no, and re-add the view.
The code looks something like this:

```
[innerView removeFromSuperView];
[innerView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[scrollView setDocumentView:innerView];
```

Then you have to set any constraints you'd like manually

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure contentView is the correct place to add it.  You may also need to update the content size.

Comment: You can't set content size on NSScrollViews, but can anyone else verify if I'm supposed to be adding to the contentView as opposed to the documentView?

Comment: No, if you add to the content view, it won't scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Adding views to a NSScrollView from IB adds the view to the NSScrollView's contentView(NSClipView).

According to your setup you have

1. NoteView is clip view(contentView) of the NSScrollView.
2. document view of the scroll view is innerview.
3. inner view(documentView)'s subview which is initialSubView is added from
   -initWithFrame: of contentView.

In an NSScrollView a contentView represents the 'clipped' representation of the documentView.
Having the documentView initialized in init of the contentView is why nothing happens.

Do This

- Add NoteView from -awakeFromNib or similar entry point as documentView of the NSScrollView.
- Add initialSubView as a subview of NoteView.

Comment: So I'm confused by your answer. Are you saying to add subviews to the contentView or the documentView?

Comment: add subviews to the document view(noteview). The document view will stretch to fit the subviews added. The contentView(NSClipView) created by default will clip/pan the document view and scrollers will be added if needed.

Comment: Unfortunately it just doesn't work well with autolayout as far as I can tell.

Comment: Oh you can add subviews via the object list outline to the left side of IB.  When you need exact placement in the hierarchy that helps a lot.